# How to set session timing in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to set the session time for my internal Sharepoint site. Is there any possible to do this?

If Sharepoint site dont get any action with in 5 Mins it will automatically get sign out.

Thanks & Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Web Applications -> Select your Web Application->Click on General Settings -> Web Page Security Validation section.